# How to change date format for Order Invoices In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, backend, date, dateformat

I want to change the date format for admin in Sales->Order(view order)->Invoices tab in 24H format

[image]

I tried to find how this grid is rendered and i found(with template path hinth) that this table is rendered in `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\ui_component\templates\listing\default.xhtml`.

```
<div
    class="admin__data-grid-outer-wrap"
    data-bind="scope: '{{getName()}}.{{getName()}}'"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../Ui/etc/ui_template.xsd">
    <div data-role="spinner" data-component="{{getName()}}.{{getName()}}.{{spinner}}" class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">
        <div class="spinner">
            <span/><span/><span/><span/><span/><span/><span/><span/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

And from here some KO js files are loaded.
I am not god at KO js and I don't know how can I do this?

Does anyone know how can I change this date format?

Answer (score 1):

To change any date to 24 format in **SALES** menu:

override `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/` xml that you need and add:`<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY, HH:mm:ss </item>` for the date filed.

As an example:

```
  <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY, HH:mm:ss </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: I have added Invoice date & time to create own field "invoice_creted_date" split by create_at. It is added in a grid with a format, but not display a formatted date in export data. So please help me how to do this thing ?

Comment: For future reference, the solution proposed by @alin is outdated as of 2.2, https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml vs https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

Comment: To change it in 2.2, you can add a <dateFormat> node within the <settings> node